# Insert record into mysql with different id (by user ID)

Tags: php, html, mysql

have this problem.

Have small web app. There are 10 users.
Every user has own form and he must fill it every day. Inserting into mysql works fine.
Problem is every user has his own numbering. YEAR-MONTH-CUSTOM-NUMBER

User 1: 202111**121**, 202111122, 202111103 etc

User 2: 202111**221**, 202111222, 202111203 etc

user 3: 202111**321**, 202111322, 202111303 etc

My question: how can I define inserting records via form for users into mysql?
For example today User1 save html form so it'll insert record into mysql with id 202111121.

Today the same user will fill form again and he must insert record with id 202111122

etc.
Thank you

Comment: Can these just be made into 4 fields?

Comment: Don't serialize datas, this goes against the purpose of using a RDBMS. A field should hold a single data, not a mix between ids and dates or whatever else

Comment: here is small table scheme:
id , user , note , custom_userid , added

Comment: Why do you need these custom numbers? What do they represent? What are they used for? It seems like just an arbitrary sequence number. Just store the year in one column, the month in another column. And you already have `id` to uniquely identify the record anyway.